# jQuery: How to print value in input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

my question is super basic, but I'm not super informed about javascript so I have 5 radio buttons(like rating) and I want to print the value when some of them is checked to input field. I end up to print it with alert and it works, but I want to print it in input.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='difficulty']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
 
            }
        });
    });


    $('.rating-star').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('.rating').find('.rating-star').removeClass('checked'); // uncheck previously checked star

        $(this).addClass('checked'); // check currently selected star

        var ratingValue = $(this).attr('data-rating'); // get rating value
        var ratingTarget = $(this).attr('data-target');

        // set the rating value to corresponding target radio input
        $('input[name="' + ratingTarget + '"][value="' + ratingValue + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form>
  <label>Question...</label>
  <br>

  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="3">
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="4">
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="5">

  <br>

  <div class="rating">
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="5" data-target="difficulty"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="4" data-target="difficulty"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="3" data-target="difficulty"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="2" data-target="difficulty"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="1" data-target="difficulty"></i>
  </div>
</form>

    <p><input type="button" value="Get Value"></p>
    <input type="text" id="radioBtn" name="printRadio">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try on method in print script as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").on('click',function(){
        var radioValue = $("input[name='difficulty']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue){
            //alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
            $('#radioBtn').val(radioValue);
        }
    });
});
```